# Cannot install pip install -r requirements.txt in Python in Windows 10

Tags: python, requirements.txt

When trying to install the requirements.txt I am getting this error below.  I tried following the instructions and downloaded

"Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

But this did not work.  I also tried changing syntax in the terminal from:

pip install -r requirements.txt to
pip install [User] -r requirements.txt

But this did not work either.

Any ideas why this will not install.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: hnswlib
  Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'hnswlib' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hnswlib
Failed to build hnswlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to detect that vc++ 14+ is installed. After you install it make sure you've restarted and double-check that installation was successful

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools. You can download and install them from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/.